# How to lock back button

Tags: android

I want to lock back button while my data process.
I use AsyncTask to process data as below:

```
class Process extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
progDailog = new ProgressDialog(ShareFolderActivity.this.getParent());
progDailog.setMessage("Loading...");
progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
progDailog.setMax(100);
progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progDailog.setCancelable(true);
progDailog.show();
lock = true;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
//process
return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
super.onPostExecute(unused);
PostLoad();
progDailog.dismiss();
lock = false;
}
}
```

And below onBackPressed():

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(!lock) {
//back action
}
}
```

When at doInBackground back button be pressed, the back action not do, but the progDailog dismiss.
How can I modify to avoid it dismiss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `progDailog.setCancelable(false);` to lock back button

Answer (score 5):

you need to set `progDailog.setCancelable(false);` for your dialog to disable hardware back-key button

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you don't want to interrupt AsyncTask background process. So as per your code, i can suggest to make some modification in your code, so that your dialog box will remain there even you press back key.

You just need to set your dialog box as not Cancelable by:

```
progDailog.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
      if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 7 
        //Instead use android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
        && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
    // This may not work on older versions of platform where it doesn't exist.
    onBackPressed();
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

return;
```

}